# Unpack Columns from CSV Document

Tags: python, csv

Looking for help unpacking columns from a CSV document.  Below is an example of data I am including.

```
'local_time_rfc822',    'Wed, 24 Jan 2018 12:57:47 -0500'
'weather',  'Overcast'
'temperature_string',   '30.2 F (-1.0 C)'
'wind_string',  'From the SE at 4.5 MPH Gusting to 6.9 MPH'
'latitude', '39.345784'
'longitude',    '-83.23734'
```

Using the following method yields rows and returns a "ValueError" where 6 values were expected, but only found 2.

```
import csv, json
from geojson import Feature, FeatureCollection, Point

    features = []
    with open('CurrentObs.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for local, weather, temp, wind, latitude, longitude in reader:
            latitude, longitude = map(float, location.strip('()').split(','))
            features.append(
                Feature(
                    geometry = Point((latitude, longitude)),
                    properties = {
                        'local': local_time_rfc822,
                        'weather': weather,
                        'temp': temperature_string,
                        'wind': wind_string
                    }
                )
            )

    collection = FeatureCollection(features)
    with open("GeoObs.json", "w") as f:
        f.write('%s' % collection)
```

Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't seem you've included any CSV data.

Comment: It may be that your CSV is the wrong way up.

Comment: Do those entries in your CSV then repeat?

Comment: Hi Martin!  They do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each row in your CSV file only contains `2` values. It is not capable of reading multiple rows to satisfy your unpack of `6` values.

Instead, to load that data in, you could use the following approach, which would give you the data in a dictionary format:

```
import csv

with open('CurrentObs.csv', newline='') as f_input:
    data = dict(csv.reader(f_input, skipinitialspace=True, quotechar="'"))

    print(data)
```

Giving you:

```
{'longitude': '-83.23734', 'temperature_string': '30.2 F (-1.0 C)', 'local_time_rfc822': 'Wed, 24 Jan 2018 12:57:47 -0500', 'wind_string': 'From the SE at 4.5 MPH Gusting to 6.9 MPH', 'weather': 'Overcast', 'latitude': '39.345784'}
```

So `data['longitude']` would give you the string: `-83.23734` or to convert it to a float:

```
data['longitude'] = float(data['longitude'])
```

It works by reading each pair of values in for each row and building a dictionary in the format `key` and `value`.